# Python 3.6.1 program failing without specifying the Python executable (Linux and Windows 7)

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a geocoding and bounding problem in **Python 3.6.1** and I am almost done. It runs fine in the *Wingware Pro 6 IDE*, Bash, and the Windows 7 command line, but only if I specify the Python executable.

**Update 1:**

Here are the settings for my python executable.
[image: Wingware python.exe]
[image: Windows command line python.exe]

**Update 2:**

After creating a small shell script on my mini Linux netbook to install pythong 3.6.1 from source...

```
clear
rm -rf Python*
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
tar -xvJf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.1
./configure
make
make install
```

... and installing Geocoder, I got this ...

[image]

Wow, holy capers Batman.

**Update 3:**

Specifying the Python binary executable first allows the command to run in Linux. Humm, what happens if I go back to the Windows 7 command prompt and do the equivalent thing?

[image: Windows 7 Python.exe and griddy]

Ugg. I just want it to run like this in windows.

```
griddy addresses1.txt
```

... and like this in Linux

```
griddy.py addresses1.txt
```

There must be something wrong with how sys.argv is being handled.

### sys.argv

> The list of command line arguments passed to a *Python script*. argv[0]
>   is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
>   full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c
>   command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string
>   '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0]
>   is the empty string.

```
sys.argv[0] #The griddy.py command itself.

sys.argv[1] #The addresses file.
```

It could be the `#!` shebang line in griddy.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

[3.4.2. Shebang Lines](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)

**Update 4:**

It just does not see the argument addresses1.txt right now.
I printed out the count and the value of sys.argv.

[image]

Fine, to Argparse we go.

[Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#)